# How to project a signal into a new range?

Tags: python, numpy, math, signal-processing

I have two signals with very different amplitude ranges:

```
sig1 = np.array([1.00e-6, 1.02e-6, 1.01e-6, 0.98e-6, 1.00e-6])
sig2 = np.array([100, 101, 103, 100, 98])
```

My goal is to project `sig1` into the basis (or range of amplitudes) of `sig2` so that I can plot them with a unified axis instead of dual *y*-axes.

My approach is to first normalize `sig1` into [0,1]:

```
sig1_norm = (sig1 - sig1.min()) / (sig1.max() - sig1.min())
```

and then undo the normalization using the range of `sig2`:

```
Sig1InSig2Range = sig1_norm * (sig2.max() - sig2.min()) + sig2.min()
```

Visually, the result looks good but I want to ensure that I'm not violating anything mathematically by doing this. I also want to be sure that I'm not distorting `sig1`, and that I preserve its shape.

Is my approach valid, or is there a more appropriate way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is valid since the distortion is equal to all values.